# How can I level a sagging concrete floor in a condo building?

Tags: concrete

I am purchasing a second floor condo that has a huge sag in a corner of one of the  bedrooms. There is approximately a 1 foot drop in the corner. The issue has been resolved in the basement footings but the building itself is off in many areas. I am on the second floor of a 5 story building. My biggest concern in trying to level the corner is the weight of any type of leveler pushing on the common wall of my neighbor next door.

Comment: You sure you want to buy this condo?

Comment: I know. Right on the water beautiful except for this issue

Comment: Before buying, you want an engineer to look at the building and confirm that the issue really has been resolved. One foot is indeed huge, even for a building that can flex... If you can't afford to get a qualified engineer to advise you both on its stability and how to deal with the problem, I would strongly suggest you reconsider buying.

Comment: I'm with keshlam on this one, you need to know what's really going on with the structure before you go any further. For one thing, concrete doesn't sag, it breaks. If a footing moved that far, something had to give. And if they say the footing has been fixed but the floor it's supporting is still a foot out of place...somethings rotten.

Comment: Demolition. 1 ft drop indicates this was badly built with major failure in the geoengineering department while the foundation was being built. Even if the footings have been "fixed" whatever that means, concrete construction doesn't handle structural failure like that well and the building integrity has been compromised. If you live in earthquake country, run in the opposite direction fast, keeping all your money with you, the "view" isn't worth it as the building will probably pancake. View some quake footage for what pancake means.

Comment: @FiascoLabs - Exactly.  Not only does this look to be a money pit and have long-term problems but the worst part is that as a condo buyer you are at the mercy of the association rules.  I might think about buying the building if my engineers spec'ed out costs... No way in hell I buy a unit.  I want to level my floor... Well you can't... or you have to use this guy... or you have to do it this way.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try it; run the other way with your money in hand instead.  The building is seriously defective beyond your control as a prospective condo purchaser, as Fiasco Labs very correctly points out in his comment.  Besides, if they're rotten enough to "fix" a footing while leaving the superstructure unrepaired, what else will they have in store?